# How to raise wait for response when a function is called in Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, delegates

i have a function that starts an EMV process. This function has a return type of void, and i am calling it in the code block below

```
public string startEMVProcess(string userpin)
    {
        btnEMVStart_Click(null, null);//this function starts the emv process
        pin = userpin;
        //i want to receive results from the EMV process here. into a global variable called 'result' and return 'result'

        }
        else
        {
            result = "Invalid Pin Length";
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here id the body of the btnEMVStartClick function

```
private void btnEMVStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] additionalTags = Common.getByteArray(tbAdditionalTags.Text);
        IDT_Device.emv_allowFallback(cbAllowFallback.Checked);

        RETURN_CODE rt = IDT_Augusta.SharedController.emv_startTransaction(Convert.ToDouble(tbAmount.Text),0, DeviceTerminalInfo.exponent, 0,30, additionalTags, false);
        if (rt == RETURN_CODE.RETURN_CODE_DO_SUCCESS)
        {
            tbOutput.AppendText("Start EMV Successful\r\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start EMV Successful");
        }
        else
        {
            tbOutput.AppendText("Start EMV failed Error Code: " + "0x" + String.Format("{0:X}", (ushort)rt) + ": " + IDTechSDK.errorCode.getErrorString(rt) + "\r\n");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start EMV failed Error Code: " + "0x" + String.Format("{0:X}", (ushort)rt));
        }
    }
```

The result from the EMV process is passed into another function by the SDK as shown below

```
private void SetOutputText(string text)
    {
        //the result from the EMV process is 'text'
        var refr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

        var param = "Referenceid:"+text;
        var res = TestISO(param);//i am doing something with 'text' here and getting a response. 
        //How can i return 'res' back to function 'StartEMVProcess'?                            
    }
```

How can i get the response 'res' returned to 'StartEmvProcess'?

Comment: Can you show the btnEMVStart_Click method? What is meant by `EMV process`? A separate executable?

Comment: I have edited the question. the btnEMVStart_Click method, starts a series of functions that reads details of a chip card and then return a response into the SetOutputText function

Comment: As I understand, the `SetOutputText(...)` function is a callback? The callback is somehow fed into the "emv" component somewhere else in your code? Maybe it would be possible to rewrite as Task Based async? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?